# Ubuntu Apache virtualhost with symfony

Tags: apache, ubuntu, symfony1, virtualhost

have a problem here with Symfony . I want to have virtual host on ubuntu so I can access my Symfony application like this app.local. What I have tried:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app.local
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
  </IfModule>
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app/web
  <Directory /var/www/app/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I added these lines to hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 app.local
```

but when I write app.local in my browser, it brings the index of my www directory(default apache page). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` in your config? Have you restarted?

Comment: Yes i have NameVirtualHost and i did restart.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app.local
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
  </IfModule>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app/web
  <Directory /var/www/app/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then apply configuration changes :

`$>sudo a2ensite mysite` // If not already enabled

`$>sudo service apache2 restart`

If the problem is not solved, check the error logs in `/var/log/apache2/`